# Installing from Xcode to iPhone lag

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

My problem is:
from a few days, when I install app on device, Xcode spend at lest 10 seconds after "Running on iPhone" message to the app really start on device.

This is the first time I have this problem but it's really annoying because it's a waist of time !

Does anyone have the same problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That happens sometimes. I've never found out any particular reason why it sometimes takes a very long time but I've learned to live with it.